# Emacs: replace file extension

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

Given a file name I want to replace the file extension to ".org"

I decided to use `replace-regexp-in-string` function:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(.*\\)\..*$" "\\1.org" "file.conserv.module")
```

Output:

```
"file.conserv.modul.org"
```

I supposed, that it will return "file.conserv.org" like in Perl program:

```
my $str = 'file.conserv.module';
$str =~ s/(.*)\..*$/$1.org/;
print $str;
```

How can I get "file.conserv.org"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can do what you want without any regular expressions:

```
(concat (file-name-sans-extension "file.conserv.module") ".org")
```

If you want to remove the path too:

```
(concat (file-name-base "file.conserv.module") ".org")
```

Comment: Yow!  This is a simpler answer -- suggest you pick this one over the regexp option.

Comment: I found a better function: file-name-sans-extension and improved your answer

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the parentheses and `.` with two backslashes in Emacs (and use `\'` rather than `$` to match the end of string):

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\\(.*\\)\\..*\\'" "\\1.org" "file.conserv.module")
```

See the bottom of [the manual node on the `\` character](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html#Regexp-Special) for more on the double-`\` escape.